# How do I change imageView in class B (custom class of controller 2) from class A (custom class of controller 1)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I've really been struggling, maybe since I'm a newbie into Objective-C, to be able to perform the following.

1. Controller MAViewControllerMenu (controller 1) holds a button that allows to select a picture from the library
2. Controller MAViewControllerPictureDisplay (controller 2) holds an imageView (bigImageView)
3. Once I select a picture from the picker in controller 1, I want to move to the next window (controller 2) and there, have the imageView holding my selected picture.

Problems:
1. It wouldn't show the next controller
2. it wouldn't change the imageView to hold my selected picture

Observations:
1. When I have the imageView on controller 1 rather than 2, it holds the picture just like I want it to
2. The debugger shows that the function to change imageView in controller 2's class is invoked. However, nothing changes, even when I tried to simply change a label.

Code:
MAViewControllerMenu.h

```
 @interface MAViewControllerMenu : UIViewController     <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker1;
    UIImagePickerController *picker2;
    UIImage *image;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;//THIS CHANGES,BUT IS IN CONTROLLER 1
}
- (IBAction)TakePhoto;
- (IBAction)ChooseExisting;
- (IBAction)movetonext;
```

MAViewControllerPictureDisplay.h

```
#import "MAViewControllerMenu.h"


@interface MAViewControllerPictureDisplay : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,menuControllerDelegate>
{


}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bigImageView;//THIS ONE WOULDNT HOLD THE CHOSEN IMAGE
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *theLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

@end
```

implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //load next page
    self.bigImageView.image = self.image;


}
```

method to react to picture selection at MAViewControllerMenu.m

```
#import "MAViewControllerMenu.h"
#import "MAViewControllerPictureDisplay.h"

@interface MAViewControllerMenu ()

@end

@implementation MAViewControllerMenu

MAViewControllerPictureDisplay* imageControllerView;

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:image]; //WORKS ON CURRENT CONTROLLER
    //imageControllerView.theLabel.text = @"hhdhdhd"; //DIDNT WORK
    [imageControllerView.bigImageView setImage:image]; //UPDATE IMAGE AT CONTROLLER 2, DIDNT WORK
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self movetonext];
}


- (IBAction)movetonext{
    [self presentViewController:imageControllerView animated:YES completion:nil];//MOVE TO NEXT WINDOW- DOESNT WORK WHEN INVOKED AFTER SELECTING A PICTURE. DOES WORK WHEN INVOKING,SAY, AFTER A BUTTON WAS CLICKED
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //load next page
    imageControllerView = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chosenImageController"];


}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your button click (the one you say IS working)?

Comment: How do you init your imageControllerView??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture does not show up in the second view controller because the image view you are setting an image does not exist yet at this point.

```
[imageControllerView.bigImageView setImage:image];
```

Declare a `UIImage` `property` and pass the image using it. Then in `imageControllerView`'s `viewDidLoad` show it in a `UIImageView`. Example:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _bigImageView.image = _image;
}
```

Comment: I did intialize it, I should have mentioned it. Will edit it now

Comment: wasn't the line [imageControllerView.bigImageView setImage:image]; supposed to do it? If not, can you please give me the code snippet to pass it and set it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. You should treat another view controller's views as private. Reecon shows the correct way to do this (set up a property to hold the information, then display that info in viewDidLoad or vieWillAppear:animated)